# Looking for text to speech in Windows 10. Suggestions?

Tags: windows-10, cortana, text-to-speech

I just moved from Mac to Windows 10. I'm used to right-clicking on an article's text and having the option to have the text read aloud to me. I have not found a way to do this in Windows 10. Cortana cannot do it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [narrator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/17173/windows-10-hear-text-read-aloud) I think. It does not quite work exactly the same way as it does on OS X.

You'll need to mess with a few settings to get it just right, but narrator cursor follows mouse cursor + setting a shortcut to turn it off and on might do the trick

Comment: Narrator is for the blind. I have played with it, but it is not a fun interface. It's also not very quick to get it to read what you want. Thank God that I am not blind!

Answer (score 1):

There are two text-to speech engines that come with Windows 10.  Go to Settings, Time and Language, and select Speech - you can chose one of the voices.  Once this is done, you'll just have to install an app like ReadAloud and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this post...I settled on the Chrome extension *Voice Instead.*

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/voice-instead/kphdioekpiaekpmlkhpaicehepbkccbf

I use Mac and PC's. I find that Chrome easily spans the two into a linear workflow, and this extension just does what I need.